# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key AnnouncementId

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to do a table that updates with a dropdown list and a box to input text but keep getting that error in the title. It is directly copied from the create cshtml.

Index.cshtml:

```
 @model Announcements1.Models.Comment



<div id="CommentDiv"></div>
<div id="CommentCreateForm">

        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AjaxCreate", "Comments",
                                new AjaxOptions
                                {
                                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                                    UpdateTargetId = "CommentDiv"
                                }))
        {

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CommentContent, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CommentContent, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CommentContent, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnnouncementId, "AnnouncementId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("AnnouncementId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnnouncementId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>


@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Custom_Scripts/BuildCommentTable.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
  }
```

CommentController:

```
 public ActionResult BuildCommentTable()
        {
            var comments = db.Comments.Include(c => c.Announcement);
            return PartialView("_CommentTable", GetMyComments());
        }






[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult AjaxCreate([Bind(Include = "CommentId,CommentContent,AnnouncementId")] Comment comment)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Comments.Add(comment);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }

            ViewBag.AnnouncementId = new SelectList(db.Announcements, "AnnouncementId", "AnnouncementContent", comment.AnnouncementId);
            return PartialView("_CommentTable", db.Comments.Include(c => c.Announcement));
        }
```

and my JS file:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Comments/BuildCommentTable',
        success: function (result) {
            $('#CommentDiv').html(result);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: have you searched ? : https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=There+is+no+ViewData+item+of+type+%27IEnumerable%3CSelectListItem%3E%27&oq=There+is+no+ViewData+item+of+type+%27IEnumerable%3CSelectListItem%3E%27&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.182j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @EhsanSajjad yes but i cant figure out the issue

Comment: The error means that `AnnouncementId` in `@Html.DropDownList("AnnouncementId", null,...)` is `null`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,you are missing the code to populate the Annoucements DropDownList data in the `BuildCommentTable` action, add it before returning the View as you did in the Post action.

Secondly that name the ViewBag key same as your Model property, your both actions should have the ViewBag populationo like:

```
ViewBag.AnnouncementOptions= new SelectList(db.Announcements, "AnnouncementId", "AnnouncementContent", comment.AnnouncementId);
```

so your get action would be like:

```
public ActionResult BuildCommentTable()
{
     ViewBag.AnnouncementOptions= new SelectList(db.Announcements, "AnnouncementId", "AnnouncementContent");
     var comments = db.Comments.Include(c => c.Announcement);
     return PartialView("_CommentTable", GetMyComments());
}
```

Same way change the post action method `ViewBag` population code part also:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AjaxCreate([Bind(Include = "CommentId,CommentContent,AnnouncementId")] Comment comment)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Comments.Add(comment);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    ViewBag.AnnouncementOptions = new SelectList(db.Announcements, "AnnouncementId", "AnnouncementContent", comment.AnnouncementId);
    return PartialView("_CommentTable", db.Comments.Include(c => c.Announcement));
}
```

and now in your view, you should be able to use strongly typed helper method `DropDownListFor` this way:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.AnnouncementId, ViewBag.AnnouncementOptions as SelectList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnnouncementId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you! the only issue im getting is in the buildCommentTable is there is no reference to the last parameter "comment"

Comment: you can remove it, it is an optional parameter

Comment: unfortunately even with your edits, i still get an error, the same one on the @html.dropdownlistfor

Comment: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'AnnouncementId'.
 at the line of @html.dropdownlistfor